# ms sql remote connection shows all db

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005

I've a db called "abc" against login "cde". When i access this db remotely MSSQL Server 2005 shows me all the databases however User "cde" can only access db "abc". How can i disable view of all database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the rights for the guest user in all the databases.

This typically isn't needed as it isn't usually a security problem to allow users to simply see what databases exist on a server.  Just because they can see them doesn't mean that they have access to them.

Comment: Can you please let me a little brief me where would i remove guest rights? because i've created a test database and guest user does not have access of it. Still when i connect to test database it shows me all the databases.

Comment: It's been a while since I needed to do this.  In newer versions you'll probably need to delete the guest user from the databases.  Again this isn't recommended and it is not a security issue for users to see databases which they can not access.